# How do I create a UITableView similar to the iOS Contacts app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I would like to create a table that is editable similar to the fields in Contacts.  They appear to be grouped, using UITableViewCellStyleValue2, but the cell style changes when it becomes editable into something that I cannot recreate that has a vertical line between the textField and the detailTextField, and the detailTextField is editable.  Is this cell a custom UITableViewCell or is there an out of the box configuration for this?

I am basically trying to create a table to edit address information exactly like this app.

Answer (score 8):

There is a sample developer IOS app called [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html) that shows how they do something like this.

In the file: IngredientDetailViewController.m when loading the table data they have the line:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EditingTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
```

Looking at the EditingTableViewCell.xib file, you see that they have a Table View Cell with a Label and Text Field, the IngredientDetailViewController passes the values for the label and text fields.

Using that trick, you should be able to easily customize the TableViewCell to your liking. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct that it is a custom cell at that point, or they've at least added some items to it.